# phpunit outputting error: PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare view()

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, behat, mink

Running Laravel 5.1 inside a Vagrant machine on a Mac.  When I try to run phpunit:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare view() (previously declared in  /vagrant/REPO/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:743) in /vagrant/REPO/bootstrap/CustomGlobals.php on line 51
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:109
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:120
PHP   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:633
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:804
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php:38
PHP   8. include_once() /vagrant/REPO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php:56
```

the View function in helper.php is wrapped in a function_exists block:

```
if (! function_exists('view')) {
/**
 * Get the evaluated view contents for the given view.
 *
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  array   $data
 * @param  array   $mergeData
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
 */
function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
{
    // there is code here
}
}
```

The view function in custom globals is in place because we wanted a way to easily separate view files by locales.

```
function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
{
    // Code here too....
}         // <- This is line 51.
```

Of course browsing the site in a browser, everything is ok.  No issues at all.  My first hypothesis is that phpunit is loading the framework in a different way.  It loads the helper.php method first, than the custom global.  Where if I am in a browser, it loads the custom global view method first.  Then the function exists if stops the helper.php method from being used.

I don't even know if that makes any sense?

Some other details:  We had phpunit working.  Then we dipped into behat/mink and now that's working, phpunit gives this error.  My second hypothesis is that the versioning to get behat/mink playing nice with laravel at the same time flipped something that now causes phpunit to not work?  Or work in a different way?

Some of my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.0",
    "xinax/laravel-gettext": "^3.0.3",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.5",
    "propel/propel": "^2.0@dev",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~2.0",
    "intervention/image": "dev-master",
    "intervention/imagecache": "~2.1",
    "braintree/braintree_php" : "^3.1.0",
    "tecnick.com/tcpdf" : "^6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-cache" : "^2.5",
    "zendframework/zend-i18n" : "^2.5",
    "illuminate/html": "^5.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.*",
    "phpunit/dbunit" : ">=1.2",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/integrated": "^0.15.6",
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master"
},
```

Any direction on this would be very much appreciated.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: whats one /vagrant/REPO/bootstrap/CustomGlobals.php line 51 ?

Comment: The final closing bracket of the method.  IE:  }

Comment: In which file are you loading `CustomGlobals.php` ?

Comment: /bootstrap/autoload.php:  require('CustomGlobals.php');

Comment: Could you debug to test which file declares the function the first time, and which function redeclares it?

Comment: When I load the website in a normal browser, CustomGlobals.php defines it.  It skips over the helpers.php definition as it has the "function_exisits" wrapped around it.  As far as I can tell, when running phpunit in the terminal, it is hitting the helper.php first.